# Beamer \onslide producing empty slides

Tags: beamer

I am having trouble getting the `\onslide` command to work. I get nothing but blank slides:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{PaloAlto}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
  \onslide<1->{One potato\\}
  \onslide<2->{Two potato\\}
  \onslide<3->{Three potato\\}
  \onslide<4->{Four\\}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I expect to see is a four slide document where the first slide says "One potato" in black and the other three lines are light grey. The next slide should show the first two lines in black, etc. Instead, I get four empty slides. If I change the numbers in the angle brackets to, say, <11->,<12->,<13->,<14-> I get ten slides with four grey lines each, and then four blank slides.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Your code works perfectly here. I guess that you have PDF viewer problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is with Kile. If I simply compile LaTeX I get the problem. With PdfLaTeX it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `\\` outside of `\onslide`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \onslide<1->{One potato}\\
        \onslide<2->{Two potato}\\
        \onslide<3->{Three potato}\\
        \onslide<4->{Four}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Sllide two:

[image]

Comment: I've tried that, and it makes no difference.

Comment: see my image ...

Comment: But the double bars should not create a new slide, only a new line.

Comment: they do not create a new slide! However, you are right, it also works for me with `\\` inside. I have up-to-date TeXLive 2015.

Comment: @Herbert, so I don't see difference if it is inside/outside braces. Sorry.